# sql: why does query repeat values when using 'GROUP CONCAT' + 'GROUP BY'?

Tags: sql, group-by, left-join, group-concat

The Query:

```
SELECT MemberId, a.MemberName, GROUP_CONCAT(FruitName) FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON 
a.MemberName = b.MemberName GROUP BY a.MemberName
```

Table a

```
MemberID          MemberName              
--------------    ----------  
1                  Al                   
1                  Al       
3                  A2
```

Table b

```
MemberName             FruitName
---------------        --------------
Al                     Apple
Al                     Mango
A2                     Cherry
```

Resulting Output from above query:

```
MemberId    MemberName  GROUP_CONCAT(FruitName)
3           A2          Cherry
1           A1          Apple,Apple,Mango,Mango
```

The actual tables I am using have 10 columns apiece so just storing everything in one table is not a workaround.  That said, how can I change the query to only return `'Apple,Mango'` for `MemberNam`e?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the keyword [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to the grouped column:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT FruitName)
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
GROUP_CONCAT(Distinct FruitName)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  MemberId, a.MemberName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT FruitName)
FROM    a
LEFT JOIN
        b
ON      a.MemberName = b.MemberName
GROUP BY
        a.MemberName
```